# Unable to read variables from a url using gorilla mux in golang

Tags: rest, unit-testing, go, gorilla, mux

I am trying to write a unit test using gotests and gomock to my restful service written in golang using gorilla but service fails to get variables from the url

Here is my request

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "product/5b5758f9931653c36bcaf0a0", nil)
```

actual endpoint is `product/{id}`

when I step into my service at the below code

```
params := mux.Vars(req)
```

`params` map is empty when it should have `id` key mapped to `5b5758f9931653c36bcaf0a0`

Strange part is endpoint works fine from post man.

**May I know whats wrong with the request?**

Comment: How does the `HandleFunce` look like?

Comment: I would log request URL and parse it with *url.ParseRequestURI* to get some info.

Comment: log the error you are getting when creating a new request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved the issue

```
req = mux.SetURLVars(req, map[string]string{"id": "5b5758f9931653c36bcaf0a0"})
```

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: This is the simplest of the solutions imo. Just do this in your test and voila!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using GET requests, you can use the http.Get function, it works as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    fmt.Println(params)
}

func main() {
    m := mux.NewRouter()
    m.HandleFunc("/products/{id}", handle)
    http.Handle("/", m)
    go func() {
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    }()
    _, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/products/765")
    // Handle Error
}
```

If you really want to use http.NewRequest, that function doesn't actually execute the request so here is what you would need:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "product/5b5758f9931653c36bcaf0a0", nil)
client := &http.Client{}
client.Do(req)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the mux Router in a separate function in the source code and call that directly in your test.

In Source code:

```
func Router() *mux.Router {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/product/{id}", productHandler)

  return r
}

func main() {
http.Handle("/", Router())
}
```

In Test:

```
func TestProductHandler(t *testing.T) {
  r := http.NewRequest("GET", "product/5b5758f9931653c36bcaf0a0", nil)
  w := httptest.NewRecorder()

  Router().ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Found the related solution in one of the google groups forums.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/Xs-Ho1feGyg/xg5amXHsM_oJ

Comment: yep, this was the correct answer. Thanks!